# How to generate similar identities to $(5+i)^4=2(1+i)(239+i)$

Tags: complex-numbers, gaussian-integers

> **Introduction:**

The Machin formula$$\frac \pi4=4\arctan\frac 15-\arctan\frac 1{239}\tag1$$Can be derived from the tangent angle formula. But $(1)$ can also be derived from the identity involving complex numbers$$(5+i)^4=2(1+i)(239+i)\tag{2}$$And similarly, other formulas can be found too. Such as$$\frac \pi4=12\arctan\frac 1{49}+32\arctan\frac 1{57}-5\arctan\frac 1{239}+12\arctan\frac 1{11043}\tag3$$$$m(1+i)=(49+i)^{12}(57+i)^{32}(239+i)^{-5}(11043+i)^{12}\tag4$$Where $m$ is a very large number.

> **Questions:**

1. How do you generate identities similar to $(1)$ and $(4)$?
2. Can you provide an example of using 1.?

> **My Work:**

The only way that I can come up with the identities is starting with$$m(1+i)=(a+i)(b+i)(c+d)(d+i)\cdots$$But that takes forever to expand, and not to mention, finding the right $a,b,c,d,\ldots$ that satisfy the equation. Is there perhaps an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea is that identities such as $(1)$ come from using the formula $$\arctan x + \arctan y = \arctan \frac{x + y}{1 - xy}.$$ Since $\frac\pi4 = \arctan 1$, we have $$\frac\pi4 = \arctan x + \arctan \frac{1-x}{1+x}$$ for any $x$ (solving for the $y = \frac{1-x}{1+x}$ that will give us $\frac{x+y}{1-xy}=1$). So we might write $$\frac\pi4 = \arctan \frac12 + \arctan \frac13$$ for example. Then we could break up each of these arctangents into smaller arctangents, and keep going.

---

So in fact we get lots and lots of identities. Which ones are the best ones? For speed of convergence, it's obviously best to have a very small value of $x$ in $\arctan x$; maybe $x = \frac1n$ for a pretty large integer $n.$ But it would *also* be nice if we could "double up" on a term: what's good about $(1)$ is that $\arctan \frac15$ is there four times, but we only need to compute it once.

We get the same arctangent twice by using the formula $$2 \arctan x  = \frac{2x}{1-x^2} \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad 2 \arctan \frac pq = \arctan \frac{2pq}{q^2-p^2}.$$
We can't make this work with $\frac{2pq}{q^2-p^2} = 1$, but we can make this very close to $1$, so that the leftover part is the arctangent of something very small. You might notice that $2pq$ and $q^2-p^2$ are two sides of a Pythagorean triple: $(2pq)^2 + (q^2-p^2)^2 = (q^2 + p^2)^2$. So we can't make them equal, because there's no isosceles right triangle with integer sides. But by solving Pell's equation, we can make them consecutive integers. More precisely, if we have a solution to $x^2 - 2y^2 = -1$, then we also have $\left(\frac{x-1}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^2 = y^2$, which we can use to get a nice double-arctangent identity.

---

For example, if we take $(x,y) = (7,5)$ (which satisfies $7^2 - 2\cdot 5^2 = -1$) then we get the Pythagorean triple $(3,4,5)$, which has $q=2$ and $p=1$. So this gives us the identity $2 \arctan \frac12 = \arctan \frac43$. When $x = \frac43$, $\frac{1-x}{1+x} = -\frac17$, so we have $$\frac\pi4 = \arctan \frac43 - \arctan \frac17 = 2\arctan \frac12 - \arctan \frac17.$$ If we take $(x,y) = (41,29)$, we get the Pythagorean triple $(20, 21, 29)$, which has $q=5$ and $p=2$, this gives us the identity $2 \arctan \frac25 = \arctan \frac{20}{21}$. When $x = \frac{20}{21}$, $\frac{1-x}{1+x} = \frac{1}{41}$, so $$\frac\pi 4 = \arctan \frac{20}{21} + \arctan \frac1{41} = 2 \arctan \frac25 + \arctan \frac{1}{41}.$$ Since $\frac25 \approx \frac13$, we could try to write $\arctan \frac25 = \arctan \frac13 + \arctan y$, and get $y = \frac1{17}$. So we can rewrite the identity as $$\frac\pi4 = 2 \arctan \frac13 + 2\arctan \frac1{17} + \arctan \frac1{41}.$$

---

We get the infamous formula with $239$ in it by taking $x=239$ and $y = 169$ as our Pell solution, which gives us the Pythagorean triple $119^2 + 120^2 = 169^2$ and $(p,q) = (5,12)$. So $2 \arctan \frac{5}{12} = \arctan \frac{120}{119}$; when $x = \frac{120}{119}$, $\frac{1-x}{1+x} = -\frac{1}{239}$, so we get the identity $$\frac\pi4 = 2\arctan \frac{5}{12} - \arctan \frac{1}{239}.$$
Here, we get extra lucky, because $5$ and $12$ form a Pythagorean triple themselves, so we can write $\arctan \frac{5}{12} = 2 \arctan \frac15$, giving you the identity $(1)$.

Comment: Great answer! But in one step, you noticed that $\frac 25\approx\frac 13$. What would we do if it was a significantly larger number? Such as $\frac {70}{169}$?

Comment: We can check out the continued fraction convergents to $\frac{70}{169}$ to find approximations to it. The already-familiar $\frac{5}{12}$ is one, and if $\arctan \frac{70}{169} = \arctan \frac{5}{12} + \arctan x$, then $x = -\frac{5}{2378}$, giving us $\arctan \frac{70}{169} = \arctan \frac{5}{12} + \arctan -\frac{5}{2738} = 2 \arctan \frac15 - \arctan \frac{5}{2738}$.

Comment: After trying a couple of generations, it seems like the $2\arctan\frac pq$ value will always have a continued fraction of $[0;2,2,2,2,2,2,2,\ldots]$. Is there a way to change that because then, the first term will always be $4\arctan\frac 15$.

Comment: The next step is probably to think about triple or quadruple arctangent formulas.